# How to localize (and X more) in laravel (v9)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

When request is invalid, that return this response:

```
{
    "message": "name را وارد کنید (and 2 more errors)",
    "errors": {
        "name": [
            "name را وارد کنید"
        ],
        "phone": [
            "phone را وارد کنید"
        ],
        "password": [
            "password را وارد کنید"
        ]
    }
}
```

But how to localize "(and 2 more errors)" to Persian?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#manual-customizing-the-error-messages

Comment: See https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/42220 for details about why Laravel does not support this

Answer (score 0):

It's currently hardcoded I'm afraid... https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Validation/ValidationException.php#L96